# Python get key from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

for some days I'm struggeling around with this:

```
dict1 = {'mainValue': [{'DOWN': {'val1': 1, 'val2': 2, 'val3': 3}}, {'UP': {'val1': -1, 'val2': -2, 'val3': -3}}]}
         
for k, v in dict1.items():
        for i in range(len(v)):
            direction = v[i]
            print(direction)
```

Output:

```
{'DOWN': {'val1': 1, 'val2': 2, 'val3': 3}}
{'UP': {'val1': -1, 'val2': -2, 'val3': -3}}
```

But I need just

```
'UP'
'DOWN'
```

How I can achieve that? I tried several `{[]}` combinations, but it didn't work.

Comment: `dict1` is local to the `main` function. You can't access it outside the function. Is the indentation in your code snippet correct?

Answer (score 2):

Change your print loop to:

```
for v in dict1.values():
    for d in v:
        direction = list(d)[0]
        print(f'direction = {direction}')
```

Since you're not using the keys of `dict1`, you can iterate over `dict1.values()` instead of `dict1.items()`.

Then you just want to print the key of the nested dictionary in each element of `v`. Converting the dictionary to a list returns a list of the keys, then you can get the first element of that to get the direction.